# Simple CSS or JavaScript loading screen for Avada wordpress site while loading a large video file that goes away after the page is finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I am trying to make a simple blank loading screen (with a percentage loaded would be amazing, but a simple looping gif works too) that hides all of my websites content while it loads. I tried all the best plugins and they all don't work, even the paid one from code canyon, so I guess I have to implement my own. unfortunately, I do not even know where to start since I have so many plugins and wordpress stuff that is happening under the hood.

My website can be found at http://eternalminerals.com, and as you can see it takes a while to load the video, and since the text loads faster than the video, for a few seconds (~13 seconds for me) the page looks very ugly.

Here is all the code of my website, I don't even know where to start on how to hide ALL of this. I am thinking I will have to wrap EVERYTHING inside a div and hide it while I play a simple gif animation?

I will keep tinkering around with this idea, but it seems like a bad idea to wrap all of this code in a div. Thank you so much!

Here is the code:

```
<style>
.alm-listing li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.alm-reveal {
  color: silver;
}
.tooltip-shortcode {
  color: #FFE396 !important;
}
</style>

[fullwidth backgroundcolor="#060F19" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="center center" bordersize="0px" bordercolor="#e5e4e4" paddingTop="30px" paddingBottom="30px"]
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px !important; color: #fff !important;">[tooltip title="Symbol: Mg, Electron configuration: Ne 3s2, Atomic number: 12, Melting point: 1,202°F (650°C), Discovered: 1755, Atomic mass: 24.305 ± 0.0006 u, Discoverer: Joseph Black"]Magnesium (Mg)[/tooltip] Deficiency: The Kingpin of All Disease?</h1>
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 17px !important; line-height: 24px !important; color: #DDEAF9!important;">Less than <strong>30%</strong> of U.S. adults consume their <strong>Recommended Dietary Allowances (RDA)</strong> of magnesium.</p>
[/fullwidth]

[raw]
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var c = document.getElementById("matrix");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//making the canvas full screen
//c.height = window.innerHeight*2;
c.height = 2540;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

//chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
var chinese = "鼠子牛丑虎寅兔兎卯龍龙辰蛇巳馬马午羊未猴申雞鸡酉狗犬戌豬猪亥李张0123456789abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
//converting the string into an array of single characters
chinese = chinese.split("");

var font_size = 10;
var columns = c.width/font_size; //number of columns for the rain
//an array of drops - one per column
var drops = [];
//x below is the x coordinate
//1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
for(var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    drops[x] = 1; 

//drawing the characters
function draw()
{
    //Black BG for the canvas
    //translucent BG to show trail
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#A3C6DC"; //blue text
    ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
    //looping over drops
    for(var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++)
    {
        //a random chinese character to print
        var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random()*chinese.length)];
        //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
        ctx.fillText(text, i*font_size, drops[i]*font_size);

        //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
        //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
        if(drops[i]*font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
            drops[i] = 0;

        //incrementing Y coordinate
        drops[i]++;
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 33);
});
</script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    //Get the canvas &
    //context var c = jQuery('#matrix');
    var c = jQuery('#matrix');
    var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var container = jQuery(c).parent();

    //Run function when browser resizes
    jQuery(window).resize( respondCanvas );

    function respondCanvas(){ 
        var textDivHeight = jQuery("#fancy-box").height();
        var textDivInnerHeight = jQuery("#fancy-box").innerHeight();
        var textDivOuterHeight = jQuery("#fancy-box").outerHeight();

        c.attr('width', jQuery(container).width()+58 ); //max width
        //c.attr('height', jQuery(container).height() ); //max height
        c.attr('height', textDivHeight+430  ); //max height

        //Call a function to redraw other content (texts, images etc)
    }

    //Initial call 
    respondCanvas();

}); 
</script>
<canvas id="matrix" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-bottom:-5px;"></canvas>
<iframe style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top: 220px;" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DLnM7jNiyrY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<style>
#fancy-box{
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    top: 430px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-top:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-bottom:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#fancy-box:before, #fancy-box:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-6px;
    width:5%; height:100%;
}
#fancy-box:before{
    right:100%;
    background:inherit;
    border-top:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-left:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-bottom:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform-origin:100% 0;

    -webkit-transform : perspective(80px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform : perspective(80px) rotateY(-2deg);
}

#fancy-box:after{
    left:100%;
    border-top:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-right:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-bottom:6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-left:none;
    background:inherit;

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;
    transform-origin:0 100%;

    -webkit-transform : perspective(80px) rotateY(2deg);
    transform : perspective(80px) rotateY(2deg);
}
</style>
<div id="fancy-box">
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Hello and welcome. I am Dr George Lundberg, and this is At Large at The Eternal Minerals of Life.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>How's your magnesium? I'll bet you don't even know. You may not think much about it. How about your various patients' magnesium? If you think calcium metabolism in health and disease is complicated, and I do, you ain't seen nothing yet. Try magnesium. With calcium, serum levels give you a pretty good idea as to whether the body has enough. With magnesium, not so well.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Approximately 99% of total body magnesium is located in bone, muscles, and soft tissues; 1% is extracellular. Thus, plasma or serum magnesium levels are only a rough approximation of adequacies of magnesium. Substantial hypomagnesemia does indicate magnesium deficiency, but normal blood levels cannot be depended upon to exclude significant depletion of magnesium stores. We "manage what we measure." If we cannot reliably measure some metabolic substance, we have far less chance to sensibly understand and manage it.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Magnesium is an essential mineral, vitally involved in more than 300 regulatory enzyme systems controlling muscle, nerve, bone, protein, DNA, glucose, and energy metabolism.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFB196!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>A "Really Big Deal"</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>The recommended daily intake of magnesium vary by age and gender, but 400 mg is a good round number, for adults. The kidneys provide homeostasis, typically excreting 120 mg per day. Since the 1960s, we have known that consumption of alcohol, even in modest amounts, can double or even quadruple the excretion of magnesium. Many over-the-counter and prescription drugs, such as proton pump inhibitors, can lower body magnesium.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFB196!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Is Magnesium the True Emperor of All Maladies?</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Magnesium deficiency has been blamed for various arrhythmias, hypertension, attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder, anxiety, seizures, leg cramps, restless legs syndrome, kidney stones, myocardial infarction, headaches, premenstrual syndrome, fibromyalgia, chest pain, osteoporosis, altitude sickness, diabetes, fatigue, weakness, and other maladies.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Whoaaa. Really? That is almost everything. Can that be true? Because of the vital nature of magnesium in so many cellular functions, it actually could be true. We just don't know.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Calcium and magnesium interact in innumerable ways. Magnesium is considered "the calming mineral."</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFB196!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>WHO: Americans Need to Consume More Magnesium</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>There has been no large systematic study of the adequacy of magnesium body stores in Americans. In 2009, the World Health Organization published a report that stated that 75% of Americans consumed less magnesium than needed. Some say that we have a nationwide magnesium deficiency. Certainly, those named illnesses are common. Obviously, the National Institutes of Health or the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention should fund serious work to ascertain the status of American magnesium body stores, and I call upon them to do so.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>For most of my professional life, I have supported the adequacy of a balanced diet and opposed the addition of nutritional supplements as unnecessary, wasteful, possibly harmful, and mostly a scam. But as the "typical" American diet has evolved into one of fast foods and processed foods, my attitude has changed.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFB196!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Eat your spinach. Take Supplements</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Foods with high magnesium content include dark leafy greens, especially kale, chard, and spinach; tree nuts and peanuts; seeds; oily fish; beans, lentils, legumes, and whole grains; avocado, yogurt, bananas, dried fruit; dark chocolate; and molasses. Supplemental magnesium is available over the counter in many forms: citrate, amino acid chelate, chloride, glycinate, malate, taurate, carbonate, and others. They vary in absorption, concentration, and bioavailability.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>Since you can't just draw a blood sample and ask the lab to tell you, if a patient has any of the symptoms I listed, you might best just try that old standby, "trial of therapy," and track what happens. Since I got interested in this topic a couple of years ago, I have emphasized the inclusion of magnesium-rich foods in my diet. Since I like to drink wine and I take occasional proton pump inhibitors, I take an additional 400 mg of magnesium daily. plus, my balanced diet.</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>I feel terrific! Better than before magnesium. I know that is subjective as all hell, but what better way would you like your patients to feel than "terrific"?</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>That's my opinion. I am Dr George Lundberg, at large at The Eternal Minerals of Life.</strong></p>
</div>
[/raw]
[fullwidth backgroundcolor="#0A0A0A" backgroundimage="" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="top left" backgroundattachment="fixed" bordersize="0px" bordercolor="#0A0A0A" paddingTop="0px" paddingBottom="0px"]
<br>
[ajax_load_more post_type="testimonials-widget" posts_per_page="5" pause="true" transition="fade" button_label="Click to show testimonials from real physicians"]
[/fullwidth]

[fullwidth backgroundcolor="#f8f8f8" backgroundimage="http://eternalminerals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/bkgd_bw2.jpg" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="top left" backgroundattachment="fixed" bordersize="1px" bordercolor="#e5e4e4" paddingTop="35px" paddingBottom="15px"]

<center>
<a href="http://amzn.to/1efaQy1" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://eternalminerals.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/magnesium-shield.gif" alt="Magnesium umbrella" style="height:999px;border:0;">
</a>
</center>

[one_half last="no"]
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px !important;"><a href="/Magnesium">Mg</a> alone...</h1>
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 17px !important; line-height: 24px !important;">is a formidable opponent against numerous diseases & conditions, including various heart arrhythmias, hypertension, attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder, anxiety, depression, stress, seizures, leg cramps, restless legs syndrome, kidney stones, myocardial infarction, headaches, premenstrual syndrome, fibromyalgia, surgery, chest pain, osteoporosis, rheumatoid arthritis, vitiligo,  vertigo/altitude sickness, diabetes, fatigue, weakness, interstitial cystitis, irritable bowel syndrome, Crohn's disease, ulcerative colitis, and other chronic diseases.<sup><a href="/references#2">2</a></sup></p>
[/one_half]

[one_half last="yes"]
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th scope="col">Age</th>
    <th scope="col">Male</th>
    <th scope="col">Female</th>
    <th scope="col">Pregnancy</th>
    <th scope="col">Lactation</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td scope="row">Birth to 6 months</td><td align="right">30 mg*</td><td align="right">30 mg*</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">7–12 months</td><td align="right">75 mg*</td><td align="right">75 mg*</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">1–3 years</td><td align="right">80 mg</td><td align="right">80 mg</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">4–8 years</td><td align="right">130 mg</td><td align="right">130 mg</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">9–13 years</td><td align="right">240 mg</td><td align="right">240 mg</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">14–18 years</td><td align="right">410 mg</td><td align="right">360 mg</td><td align="right">400 mg</td><td align="right">360 mg</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">19–30 years</td><td align="right">400 mg</td><td align="right">310 mg</td><td align="right">350 mg</td><td align="right">310 mg</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">31–50 years</td><td align="right">420 mg</td><td align="right">320 mg</td><td align="right">360 mg</td><td align="right">320 mg</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row">51+ years</td><td align="right">420 mg</td><td align="right">320 mg</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tbody>
<caption align="top" style="padding: 11px;">Table 1: RDAs for Magnesium <sup><a href="/references/#4" class="fscopy_nounderline">4</a></sup></caption>
</table>
[/one_half]

[rev_slider captions_tall]
<br>
[one_half last="no"]
[title size="2"]Magnesium (Mg)...[/title]
[checklist icon="star" iconcolor="dark" circle="no"]
<ul>
    <li>...has the ability to suppress the release of adrenocorticotropic hormones (ACTHs) via the hippocampus.</li>
    <li>ACTHs serve to trigger the additional release of the stress hormones cortisol and adrenaline from the adrenal glands, and magnesium reduces the responsiveness of the adrenal glands to the ACTHs, thus reducing the damage of any external sources of stress you may face during your daily routine to your mind and body.</li>
    <li>Additionally, magnesium has the ability to protect the brain at the blood brain barrier by blocking any stress hormones from entering.</li>
    <li>Magnesium is also known to relax smooth muscle cells by reducing intracellular calcium and to exhibit an anti-inflammatory effect by balancing T-cells and suppressing mast cells. </li>
    <li>Magnesium is a component of almost every chemical reaction that takes place in the body. 24 hours a day, seven days a week.</li>
    <li>Magnesium is used by every organ in the body, especially the heart, muscles and kidneys.</li>
    <li>Building proteins for muscle requires magnesium.</li>
    <li>This important mineral regulates blood pressure and blood sugar levels and can be found in every cell in the body.</li>
    <li>Since chronic stress is known to cause premature death and chronic disease, and in addition to all the previously listed reasons, is why I call magnesium "the kingpin of all disease".</li>

</ul>
[/checklist]
[/one_half]

[one_half last="yes"]
<center>
[layerslider id="3"]
</center>
[/one_half]
<center>
<iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=eternminer-20&o=1&p=48&l=ur1&category=primemain&banner=1PREMK5A0BD4VB6F8Y02&f=ifr&linkID=JWB64QKJDTI65NQH" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</center>
[counters_box]
[counter_box value="321000" unit="K" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]Current population of the US (June 2015)[/counter_box]
[counter_box value="224700" unit="K" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]People in the US who require more magnesium[/counter_box]
[counter_box value="1229" unit="&cent;" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]Cost per bottle of <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002SKUWI" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Solgar Magnesium Citrate Tablets, 120 Count</a><img src="http://ir-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=eternminer-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B0002SKUWI" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
[/counter_box]
[counter_box value="2761563" unit="K" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]Cost to cure magnesium deficiency in the US[/counter_box]
[/counters_box]

<center>
<img src="http://eternalminerals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/mg-balance2.gif" alt="" style="width:90%;"/>
</center>

[counters_box]
[counter_box value="7248000" unit="K" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]Current population of the World (June 2015)[/counter_box]
[counter_box value="5073600" unit="K" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]People in the World who require more magnesium[/counter_box]
[counter_box value="1229" unit="&cent;" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]Cost per bottle of <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002SKUWI" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Solgar Magnesium Citrate Tablets, 120 Count</a><img src="http://ir-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=eternminer-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B0002SKUWI" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
[/counter_box]
[counter_box value="62354544" unit="K" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" border="yes" color="" direction="up"]Cost to cure magnesium deficiency in the World[/counter_box]
[/counters_box]
[/fullwidth]

[fullwidth menu_anchor="features" backgroundcolor="" backgroundimage="" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="top left" backgroundattachment="fixed" bordersize="1px" bordercolor="#e5e4e4" paddingTop="25px" paddingBottom="25px"]

<center>
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_cw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Feternminer-20%2F8010%2Fe00f7ff5-1dc1-4ba8-b2bb-f7fde05f52be&Operation=GetScriptTemplate"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_cw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V20070822%2FUS%2Feternminer-20%2F8010%2Fe00f7ff5-1dc1-4ba8-b2bb-f7fde05f52be&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.com Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</center>

<br>

[scrapeazon asin="B0002SKUWI" height="1325" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B001G7QM0I" height="1225" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B00DUY8F78" height="1250" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B00HZWHGJ4" height="1625" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B00HG4P5P8" height="1280" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B00CB6BIYS" height="1280" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B0094A3JBY" height="1360" border="false" country="us"]
[scrapeazon asin="B00686TQGO" height="1220" border="false" country="us"]

<iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=eternminer-20&o=1&p=49&l=ur1&category=primemain&banner=1R9K5BAQYT4E81TYGR02&f=ifr&linkID=ACYBZNMA2VWGY3DF" width="300" height="600" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
[/fullwidth]

[fullwidth backgroundcolor="" backgroundimage="http://eternalminerals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/bkgd_bw2.jpg" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="top left" backgroundattachment="fixed" bordersize="1px" bordercolor="#c6c6c6" paddingTop="10px" paddingBottom="0px"]
[two_third last="no"]
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px !important;">Join The 70,000+ Satisfied Magnesium Users!</h1>
[/two_third]
[one_third last="yes"]
[separator top="7" style=""]
<p style="text-align: center;">[button link="http://eternalminerals.com/got-mg/" color="custom" size="large" type="flat" shape="round" target="_blank" title="" gradient_colors="transparent" gradient_hover_colors="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)" accent_color="rgba(0,0,0,.5)" accent_hover_color="#333333" bevel_color="" border_width="2px" shadow="no" icon="" icon_divider="yes" icon_position="left" modal="" animation_type="bounce" animation_direction="up" animation_speed="1" class="" id=""]I'M SOLD, BUY NOW![/button]</p>
[/one_third]
[/fullwidth]
```

Comment: are you saying you want to use a large video file as a loading screen?

Comment: no I want the user to see a simple loading bar or a looping gif while the page loads the large video file. I dont want to use a large video file as a loading screen. and once the large video file/everything is all loaded, i would like the loading screen to go away

Comment: ok - your question sounded like you did

Comment: @JaromandaX I have to agree with you. I think the title needs to be updated as it appears to be misleading/confusing.

Comment: thank you for that, Jaromanda X, i fixed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few days ago, I implemented this in one of my projects. Works perfectly and does exactly what you want. If you need help installing it, I am here.

https://github.com/Gaya/queryloader2

Comment: I already installed in on my site, my only complaint is that it still shows my ugly site for a second, then the loading screen, then shows the ugly site for another second, then finally it shows the site fully loaded

Comment: But I think that is because I didn't put the code in the <head> I just inserted it into the page

Comment: Hehe! No problem! It was time to give something back to the community! :D. Nice to see I could help. Cheers

Comment: You have to place it as high as you can. So that it loads it as soon as possible. Dont place the small script at the bottom of the page. Place it at the beggining of the body.

Comment: Place the <script src="queryloader2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> at the head, and the rest of the code, just below body start.

Comment: This is amazing!!! The crappy plugins I bought didn't even work as well as this! Wish that money went to you instead! I can send you some bitcoin if you have a bitcoin wallet!

Comment: Hehe! No problem! I am sure i will get some answers in my questions in here too :D

Comment: I believe you should also try to reduce the http requests. Try this free tool to see if it works for you:  Autoptimize https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/ and also this one for caching and speed: WP-Super-Cache

Comment: Do you think WP-Super-Cache is better than W3 Total Cache? I am currently using W3 Total Cache.

Comment: I dont know, i believe they are the same thing. If you are using one of them, ok. But try to use something like autoptimize, because I think 348http requests are massiveeee :-)